# Will it hurt SEO to have mobile URLs that end in "/AMP" when the same desktop URLs don't?

Tags: seo, url, mobile, amp

Is having `/AMP` at the end of the URL for mobile not good for search engines compared to a regular URL?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is good - if used correctly.
Google developed the amp project for better performance using mobile devices.

Some good reads:
https://www.ampproject.org/

Comment: sure, dont forget to mark the answer as helpful and vote it up - if this is what you where searching for :-)

Comment: For sure, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just putting `/Amp` won't add any value. If you want to introduce Mobile page follow this advice: https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls

If you want to introduce AMP on your website, then talk to your developer because AMP HTML syntax is different. 
https://www.ampproject.org/learn/overview/

Example:

- Actual URL: `https://www.example.com/store/reliance-trends`
- AMP URL: `https://www.example.com/store/reliance-trends/amp`

Add below in text on your mobile & Desktop version Pages inside `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/store/reliance-trends/amp" >
```